# Creating a function to compare multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, list, dataframe, function, loops

**Question:**

I am trying to create a function that will compare two Excel-based DataFrames and only outputs the differences (greater than 0.01) while ignoring NA values. The function should ideally show the corresponding row number and column number (i.e. Excel col A=1, B=2, C=3) for the differing values. To save time, I have used `glob` to recursively locate all my .XLSX files and created two list of DataFrames for comparison purposes.

**Issue:**

My function outputs some values that are equal (to at least 9-10 sig figs). When I copy my variable outputs into Excel to see the value, I get the following:
[External link to sample output for DataFrame comparison][1], where there should only 3 values outputted rather than 26 as seen in the image linked above.

When I apply rounding and dtype converting into my `diff_pd` function it does not seem to be working. When I apply it in my looping section it also does not work. I believe my issue is caused by a rounding or a dtype difference. However, when I used `assertIsInstance()` unit test, I got the following output that shows my dtypes are the same.

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   LL      26 non-null     float64
 1   LC      26 non-null     float64
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Function:**

```
def diff_pd(df1, df2):
    """Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
    assert (df1.columns == df2.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if any(df1.dtypes != df2.dtypes):
        "Data Types are different, trying to convert"
        df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
    if df1.equals(df2):
        return None
    else:
        # need to account for np.nan != np.nan returning True
        diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['row #', 'col #']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
        changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]
        changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
        return pd.DataFrame({'LL': changed_from, 'LC': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)
```

**My loop function:**

```
# Loop through 2nd directory and create list of files with XLSX extension
os.chdir(input_drc1)
extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('0*.{}'.format(extension))]
```

**Reading in files as list of dataframes:**

```
## Read in data from list of XLSX files
list_banks1 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Total (except non-resident)',skiprows=16, nrows=360, usecols='E:AR', dtype='float') for filename in all_filenames]
```

**Manipulate my dataframes (tried rounding on this step):**

```
# Drop column 14 from all DataFrames in list of DataFrames
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.index +=1
```

**Looping to create dataframes with unique name:**

```
##Create unique DataFrames for each DataFrame in list
    list_banks = ["000","002","004","005","015","017","019","021","024","029","030","032","033","034","038","039"]
    for i in range(0,len(list_banks)):
        globals()[f'df{list_banks[i]}LL'] = list_banks1[i]
```

I could not figure out how I could loop to match and compare the two lists without creating unique dataframe variable names.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well my main focus was the function section and not the full code, but added it in just in case someone wanted to peruse it. However, I understand seeing it in its entirety can be difficult, so I will trim it and create a minimal reproducible example when I get free time in the next few days. Thank you.